# sudo: python3: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sudo, python-3.9, rhel6

I have installed python39 on the RHEL6 using source.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#on-linux

After the setup was completed I was trying to get the version of various python on the Operating system through a non-root user but it results below :

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config /usr/local/lib/python3.9
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config /usr/local/lib/python3.9 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo python3 -V
sudo: python3: command not found
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo python3.9 -V
python3.9: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

I am looking for the assistance on why the non-root user not able to execute python3 version.

Comment: Might want to `whereis libssl` and check your ld path. You can't run `python3` beacuse  the symlinks aren't set up; I'm not sure whose job that is when installed from source (normally you install from a distro package that takes care of it)

Comment: Actually, your very link mentions `make install` vs `make altinstall`. Since you're installing in `/usr/local` it should be fine to do the full thing.

Comment: @tink `sudo` may use a different PATH than that, actually; usually `Defaults        secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. I'm not sure if there's a blessed way of getting it programmatically (since there may be multiple config files), but `sudo env | grep ^PATH=` might do the trick.